# only one field fail to validate using jquery validation plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

i have a form with some input fields , i want to make client side validation using jquery validation plugin, it works fine but only **notification input filed** doesnt show the error message when it is empty, i dont knw what's wrong . here is my code

**my form input fields**

```
<div class="well">
      <form id="register-form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <legend>Adding new  products </legend>
        <?php  if(!empty($_SESSION['success'])){ 
         echo '<div class="alert alert-success">'.$_SESSION['success'].'</div>'; unset($_SESSION['success']);} ?>


        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-ban-circle"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name of the product"
                     value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name); ?>">
                </div>
                 <span class="error"><?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="control-group ">
            <label class="control-label">Category</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-pills"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="category" name="category" placeholder="Computer,Tv, Phone etc"
                    value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($category)?>">
               </div>
               <span class="error"><?php echo $categoryErr;?></span>
            </div>
        </div>

         <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Quantity</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-ban-circle"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" id="quantity" class="input-mini" name="quantity" placeholder="Quantity"
                    value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($quantity);?>">
                </div>


               <select class="selectpicker remove-example" name="per" id="per" selected="true">

                     <?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $_POST['per']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $_POST['per']; ?></option>
                    <?php }else{ ?>
                          <option value="">Choose amount</option>
                    <?php } ?>
                     <option value="" disabled="disabled"> -------------------- </option>


                        <option value="unit">unit</option>
                        <option value="dozen">dozen</option>
                        <option value="box">box</option>
                 </select>
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $quantityErr.$perErr;?></span>
            </div>

        </div>


        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Buying Price</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-dollars"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="input-small" id="buying_price" name="buying_price" placeholder="Product Price"
                    value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($buying_price); ?>">
                </div>
                <span id="per_text" style="color:#F96;"></span>
                 <span class="error"><?php echo $buy_priceErr; ?></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Selling Price</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-dollars"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="input-small" id="selling_price" name="selling_price" placeholder="Selling Price"
                    value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($selling_price); ?>">
                </div>
                <span id="per_text1" style="color:#F96;"></span>
                 <span class="error"><?php echo $sell_priceErr; ?></span>
            </div>
        </div>

         **<div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Notification amount</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-arrow-down"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="input-large" id="notify" name="notify" placeholder="notify me when amount is"
                    value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($notify); ?>">
                </div>
                <span id="per_text2" style="color:#F96;"></span>
                 <span class="error"><?php echo $notifyErr; ?></span>
            </div>
        </div>**





        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Expire Date</label>
            <div class="controls">
            <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-time"></i></span>

           <td><input type="text" name="date"  id="date"   class="span2" placeholder="Expire date" 
           value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($date); ?>"/>
            </div>
              <span class="error"><?php  echo  $dateErr.$dateInvalid; ?></span>
     </div>
       </div>


        <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label"></label>
          <div class="controls">

           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" >Add</button>

          </div>

    </div>

      </form>

   </div>
```

**my Jquery validation file**

```
    (function($,W,D)
{
var JQUERY4U = {};

JQUERY4U.UTIL =
{
    setupFormValidation: function()
    {
        //form validation rules
        $("#register-form").validate({
            rules: {

                name: "required",
                category: "required",
                buying_price: "required",
                selling_price: "required",
                quantity: "required",
                per: "required",
                datu: "required",
                notify: "required",
                date: "required",

        });
    }
}

//when the dom has loaded setup form validation rules
$(D).ready(function($) {
    JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
});

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

any help guys?

Comment: u want validation to take place on button click,right?why there is ** on following code?**<div class="control-group">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is spell mistake in reference to the element `date` in your validator. You are using `datu` instead of `date`.

Change:

```
datu: "required",
```

To:

```
date: "required",
```

Comment: You are welcome. Do it calmly it will increase your debugging ability.